# getting digital envelope error when I try to run React18 app

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, webpack

For some odd reason my working React18 app now has broken and I didn't change anything in terms of node modules or scripts etc. Now when I run the app using **npm run dev**, I get below errors

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/ddd/thank-you-cards-new/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:90:53)
    at Normal
```

My package.json has below line under scripts section ...I use **npm run dev** to run my app

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "export REACT_APP_ENV=DEVELOPMENT PORT=7011 && react-scripts start",
}
```

my core node modules are as per below ...

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "react-colorful": "^5.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-idle-timer": "^5.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
```